# Tone() working on all digital pins?

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm

Looking at my Arduino Uno board, it appears the digital PWM pins are #11, #10, #9, #6, #5 and #3.

When playing around with the Theremin, it seems that the `Tone()` message works on all pins regardless of whether they are marked PWM or not?

Can anyone explain what is happening or how this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tone library doesn't use the PWM mode timer functions on the atmega, instead it uses an interrupt routine to toggle the pins. You can find the source code for Tone libary here for reference:

https://github.com/johnmccombs/arduino-libraries/blob/master/Tone/